# Is it a case of omission of subject relative pronoun, a mistake or a set phrase?

Tags: grammar, usage, relative-pronouns

**[SOURCE](https://books.google.com/books?id=NX3kwwM4QC4C&pg=PT165&lpg=PT165&dq="He's+a+creature+come+straight+out+of+a+nightmare")**

I stumbled upon this sentence:

> 'He's not a horse, he's—he's a creature come straight out of a nightmare.'

Is it a case of omission of subject relative pronoun?

> "he’s a creature ***that/who has*** come out of a nightmare."

If yes, why is it possible to omit the subject relative pronoun? Is it informal English or a mistake?
If not, it it some sort of set phrase?

Comment: For me, "a creature [who  has] come straight out of a nightmare" is a typical speech ellipsis. This is a dialogue, right?

Comment: @Lambie It's dialogue, aye, but it's a "fantasy" novel, and the use of pseudo-archaisms is _de rigueur_. _"Fain would I master yon dragon!"_

Comment: I would say this: it is elliptical speech. I would never say it is a pronoun, come what may. And I am not sure it is pseudo-archaic. It's more regional.

Comment: @P.E. Dant I don't think assuming elided words is more complicated than your explanation. As for "come what may", that is not like the example. And yes, "remnant of the subjunctive" if you must. Personally, I don't think English ever had a subjunctive but those Latinists didn't know what to call it.

Comment: @Lambie It's not **_I_** who calls this _come_ a remnant of the subjunctive, it's Huddleston & Pullum! It's accurate to say that "English" as we know it never had a subjunctive (nor even "voices" for that matter) but the older, inflected languages from which our modern English arose absolutely had them. Call it "subjunctive" or "flamgully", what does the label matter? In this case, the writer strives for pseudo-archaic tone. It's standard for a "bodice-ripper" like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern English, the past participle of *come* is *come*. (In the 14th and 15th centuries, it was sometimes *comen*, cf. *driven* for the verb *drive*.)

This *come* is that *past participle* of *come*. This is a somewhat archaic, or regional and vernacular usage of this particular participle, but it is not uncommon to use the past (or present) participle of English verbs as adjectives in the *postnominal* position. Consider:

- He's a creature **summoned** straight out of a nightmare.
- It was a car **driven** off the road.
- They were an army **drowned** in the tide.

Whenever a past participle is used as an adjective in the postnominal position, it is of course possible to add a helper verb and relative pronoun as its subject:

- It was a car (*that was*) **driven** off the road.
- They were an army (*that was*) **drowned** in the tide.

However, the helper verb and relative pronoun are not omitted from the original sentences, and neither are they omitted from your example:

- He's a creature (*<s>who has</s>*) **come** out of a nightmare

Comment: Not sure you have reason here. [said on purpose as a joke].

Comment: @Lambie Imagine the food fight if I had included something about the unaccusative!

Comment: +1 (but I think you mean *postnomi**n**al*.) It's not irrelevant that in older English the perfect of verbs of motion was formed with *BE*, not *HAVE*, so if you subscribe to the notion that postnominals are reduced relatives this use of *come* is ordinary Whiz deletion.

Comment: @StoneyB Do you seriously think the OPs around here have any clue what you and P.E. Dant are  on about?

Comment: @Lambie The OPs? Hell, half the time I _myself_ don't know what I'm on about.

Comment: @P.E. Dant I'll bear that in mind.

Comment: And then it would be a thing borne in mind.

Comment: lhude sing goddamn.

Comment: Incidentally, the conjugation isn't terribly relevant to the dropping of the relative pronoun. As long as we're talking about archaicisms and regionalisms, take Milton, for example, who sometimes wrote phrases with structures like "It is a people sails across the world"

Comment: @LukeSawczak The point of the answer, though, is that it really _isn't_ an ellipsis. The relative pronoun isn't dropped. See Tᴚoɯɐuo's "borne" above. This is a simple adjectival use of the past participle _come_, just as the pp of _drown_ is used in _"They were an army **drowned** in the tide."_ There's another interpretation per CGEL that views this _come_ as a remnant of a subjunctive, but I'm not going there...

Comment: @P.E.Dant That's true, and I was wondering the same under the influence of French with its sentences like « C'est un oiseau venu de loin »...

Comment: @StoneyB For the purposes and duration at least of this answer, I must unsubscribe, but there certainly are good historical arguments for that case.